# Disable normal scrollwheel functionality in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using the mousewheel plugin, I have:

```
$('html, body').bind("mousewheel", function(objEvent, intDelta){
if (intDelta > 0 && $currentPage != 1){
    $currentPage--;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#page"+$currentPage).offset().top}, 2000);
}
else if (intDelta < 0 && $currentPage != 4){
    $currentPage++;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#page"+$currentPage).offset().top}, 2000);
}
});
```

Which works fine, but whenever I scroll, it scrolls up or down the page a tick first before doing the animation. Is there any way to disable this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a

```
return false;
```

Before the last brace.

```
$('html, body').bind("mousewheel", function(objEvent, intDelta){
if (intDelta > 0 && $currentPage != 1){
    $currentPage--;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#page"+$currentPage).offset().top}, 2000);
}
else if (intDelta < 0 && $currentPage != 4){
    $currentPage++;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#page"+$currentPage).offset().top}, 2000);
}
return false;
});
```

BTW, you should use .on() instead of .bind()